# When isn't an IRI enough of a value in JSON-LD?

Tags: json-ld

I'm playing around with [JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org) but I think I'm missing something about linking. [Gregg Kellogg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/830293/gregg-kellogg)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32280426/2766176) to [Repeat whole JSON-LD structure or only the ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32122087/2766176) almost clears it up for me, but not quite.

He has an example like this, where the author is an organization:

```
{
  ...
  "author": {
    "@id" : "http://example.com",
    "name": "My Organization"
  }
}
```

Which he simplifies at the end to look like this:

```
{
   ...
   "author": {"@id" : "http://example.com"}
}
```

It seems to me that if I wanted to link to something, I should be able to simply reference it:

```
{
   ...
   "author": "http://example.com"
}
```

That value would be seen as an IRI (assuming author is defined correctly) and that something would inflate the object at that IRI. However, almost all of the examples I see have extra stuff around that. What am I missing here? What can't I do if I just use the IRI instead of the method Gregg uses? He says that some people repeat parts of the graph, but that would seem to be a huge problem in managing data should I have to change a name. Is there a practical or theoretical problem there?

The [sample on json-ld.org](http://json-ld.org) seems to be what I expect, but the things I've seen most often don't do it like this (linking to `spouse`):

```
{
  "@context": "http://json-ld.org/contexts/person.jsonld",
  "@id": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/John_Lennon",
  "name": "John Lennon",
  "born": "1940-10-09",
  "spouse": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cynthia_Lennon"
}
```

I think in the end if doesn't matter because [Markus Lanthaler also notes that you can't rely on parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32146793/2766176) to inflate objects so you're stuck specifying everything all the time just in case.